# vue-cli · Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/webpack: self signed certifi cate in certificate chain

Tags: node.js, vue.js

This error shows when I try to run a vue init webpack command.

vue-cli · Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/webpack: self signed certifi
cate in certificate chain

What's the problem?
I want to proceed and learn vue and done my project T_T

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my antivirus, turn off the settings about security connection.

Comment: If your antivirus is injecting its own SSL certificates, it's a bigger security risk than pretty much anything else on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`npm install -g npm@latest`
`vue-init webpack my-project`
`vue-init webpack-simple my-project`

GL

Comment: try uninstall and reinstall node and vue-cli, appears this problem